# What is the method execution priority in Python when a .py file contains __name__==__main?

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python and came across the code `if __name__ == '__main__':`

I have two python modules.

1. one.py
2. two.py

In one.py:

```
import two
def func_in_one():
    print('function from one.py')

print('Top level in one.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_in_one()
    two.func_from_two
```

In two.py:

```
print('Top level in two.py')
def func_from_two():
    print('function from two.py')
```

On terminal, when I run `python one.py` I see the following output

```
Top level in two.py
Top level in one.py
function from one.py
function from two.py
```

From what I understood `__name__ == '__main__':` is used to organize the code like setting up the order of calling methods & imported methods we want to.

In that block of code I am first calling `func_in_one()` and the zero indention code takes priority.
The function `func_in_one()` from my one.py is the first executed statement instead `Top level in two.py` gets printed and then comes `Top level in one.py` and `function from one.py` and at last `function from two.py` is printed.

If I am calling func_in_one() and it is in the current module of my .py file, why is the output not

```
Top level in one.py
function from one.py
Top level in two.py
function from two.py
```

This is my first time using `__name__ == __main__` and it is a bit confusing. Could anyone care to explain the execution pattern here ?

Comment: The `__name__ == '__main__' ` guard is so that you can execute certain code *only if* the file is directly called from the shell, vs. being imported by another module. The file that is passed as an argument to the interpreter is the only one should have \_\_name__ set to \_\_main__. If you say, call a function without the guard it will *always* be called, even when you just import something into another file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Coming from JVM language(Scala).. Kind of early hiccups. But understood the concept now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file is first imported, its code gets executed from top to bottom. If something else happens in that (e.g. another file gets imported), the code pauses to do that, then resumes executing from top to bottom.

`if __name__ == '__main__':` is just a normal `if` statement - it just looks special initially because none of the tutorials explain what it does. What it does is check whether the hidden built-in variable `__name__` has a specific value `'__main__'`, which only happens when the current file is the one that was directly executed from the command line (e.g. if you do `python one.py`, then `__name__` in `one.py` will evaluate to `'__main__'`, whereas `__name__` in `two.py` will evaluate to `two`. The python interpreter sets the value of `__name__` automatically).

Putting this all together, here's what happens in your case:

1. You start executing `one.py` from top to bottom
2. The first line of `one.py` is `import two`, so we grab `two.py` and start executing that from top to bottom

   1. We encounter and execute the statement `print('Top level in two.py')` and execute it
   2. We encounter a `def func_from_two():` statement. We evaluate (but do not execute) the function and add it to `two`'s namespace so that other things can access it.
   3. We reach the bottom of `two.py`.
3. Continuing down `one.py`, we find a `def func_from_one():` statement. We evaluate (but do not execute) the function and add it to the namespace so we can use it later.
4. Next, we encounter and execute the statement `print('Top level in one.py')`
5. We hit the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, and evaluate whether the condition is true. In this case, it is, since we executed this file by calling `python one.py` instead of by importing it with `import one` (in which case it would be false)
6. We call `func_from_one()`, which prints `'function from one.py'`
7. We call `two.func_from_two()`, which prints `'function from two.py'`

Comment: Easiest to understand. But I didn't understand two things from answer:
`if something else happens in that (e.g. another file gets imported), the code pauses to do that, then resumes executing from top to bottom.`
Another one would be `why print statements are executed but not functions are considered`. Are there any other statements like PRINT which are executed when an import statement is encountered ?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `print()` is a function like any other, and we're just calling it. 'Statement' is somewhat overloaded terminology, but an *expression* (which includes function calls) is one example of one. By the same token, if you were to call `two.func_from_two()` outside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, it would work perfectly fine. The reason `import` and `def` do something different is because they're keywords that the interpreter specifically treats in a special way. Defining a function and calling a function aren't the same thing.